# site loads in Ubuntu but not in any browser in XP

Tags: windows-xp, firefox, dns

I'm volunteering for an organization which uses shiftboard.com to schedule shifts.

I have a dual-boot setup with WinXP and Ubuntu on my laptop.

When I'm in XP, shiftboard.com (or any variations of that URL) won't load in either Firefox or Chrome. I get "Problem loading page/ The connection has timed out / The server at www.shiftboard.com is taking too long to respond."

When I boot into Ubuntu, this page loads fine (Firefox browser.)

I looked at my hosts file in WinXP and there are no sites blocked that way.

I'm mystified. What would do this?

Comment: On Windows, **Run** `cmd.exe` and enter the following command: `ipconfig /all`. Update your question with the **DNS Servers** for your main network interface (e.g. Wireless or LAN). Also, try `ipconfig /flushdns` to clear your DNS cache. Let us know if that makes any difference.

Comment: DNS Servers listed: 75.75.75.75 and 75.75.75.76 . ipconfig /flushdns didn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

1. When you ping the site in XP, does it respond with the correct IP? (If not, perhaps your DNS server is set incorrectly)
2. Can you open the page in Internet Explorer? (Perhaps there is something wrong with the configuration of Firefox and Chrome, such a proxy settings)
3. Are there any other anomalies while browsing in XP? (Are there general network issues you can replicate)

Comment: When I ping in XP it says reply from http://67.212.132.26/, which resolves to the shiftboard site when I open it from my phone. (I didn't want to reboot into linux right now.)

Comment: 2. It won't open in Internet Explorer. (Sorry, I left that out just because I try to avoid IE.  3. And no other anomalies I've noticed in XP, really.

Comment: have you tried restoring default settings for firefox/chrome?....any addons that might cause this?